# Translate text into english under certain conditions, python

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a function that takes in a dataframe and a boolean list. If a value in the boolean list is 0 then we know where the text is not english. I wrote this function but I do not think its pythonic and follows best practices.

```
def translate_text(df, mask):
    gs = goslate.Goslate()
    for sd, d, r, m in zip(df['short_description'], df['details'], df['resolution'], mask):
        if m == 0:
            # Perform translation
            sd = gs.translate(sd, 'en')
            d = gs.translate(d, 'en')
            r = gs.translate(r, 'en')
            
    return df
```

Is there a more pythonic way of achieving the latter? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here is a sample

```
d = {'short_description': ['There is a problem with the laptop', 'Problemo y computer', 'There is a problem with the screen'],
    'details': ['The laptop will not respond, just a black screen', 'Problemo y computer', 'The screen is just blinking'],
    'resolution': ['Laptop has been replaced', 'La computadora ha sido reemplazada', 'Screen has been replaced']}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
mask = [1,0,1]
```

**Update:**

I decided to draw a bounty for this question. I want to note that the above example assumes we have one mask for all three columns. This is just for simplicity. In reality there is a unique mask vector for each column. Please ask for clarification if that does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your input a little bit to reflect the follow-up question for different masks for each column. I'm not sure if it makes sense with the texts though (every line should be the same language), but as long as it's just for illustration:

```
d = {'short_description':
         ['There is a problem with the laptop', 'Problemo y computer', 'There is a problem with the screen'],
     'details':
         ['The laptop will not respond, just a black screen', 'The screen is just blinking', 'La computadora hace un ruido raro'],
     'resolution':
         ['La computadora ha sido reemplazada', 'Laptop has been replaced', 'Screen has been replaced']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

---

```
                    short_description                                           details                          resolution
0  There is a problem with the laptop  The laptop will not respond, just a black screen  La computadora ha sido reemplazada
1                 Problemo y computer                       The screen is just blinking            Laptop has been replaced
2  There is a problem with the screen                 La computadora hace un ruido raro            Screen has been replaced
```

I'd recommend creating a dataframe with your masks as well like this:

```
masks = pd.DataFrame({"short_description": [1, 0, 1], "details": [1, 1, 0], "resolution": [0, 1, 1]})
masks = np.logical_not(masks.astype(bool))
```

If you are free to choose, I would actually flip your masks and put True where the text needs to be translated and False where it is in english already. Something like this (the example above creates the same DataFrame).

```
masks = pd.DataFrame({"short_description": [False, True, False], 
                      "details": [False, False, True], 
                      "resolution": [True, False, False]})
```

---

```
   short_description  details  resolution
0              False    False        True
1               True    False       False
2              False     True       False
```

During testing I ran into a `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests` with goslate. According to the [pypi-page](https://pypi.org/project/goslate/) the project is no longer updated for that reason... So I ended up using google translate instead (The final solution should work the same with goslang).

> pip install deep_translator

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
gt = GoogleTranslator(source='es', target='en')
```

**You can then apply gt.translate to your dataframe and update the spanish text like this:**

```
df.update(df.apply(lambda col: col.loc[masks[col.name]].apply(gt.translate)))
```

---

```
                    short_description                                           details                      resolution
0  There is a problem with the laptop  The laptop will not respond, just a black screen  The computer has been replaced
1                problem and computer                       The screen is just blinking        Laptop has been replaced
2  There is a problem with the screen                  The computer makes a weird noise        Screen has been replaced
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

gt = GoogleTranslator(source='es', target='en')

d = {'short_description':
         ['There is a problem with the laptop', 'Problemo y computer', 'There is a problem with the screen'],
     'details':
         ['The laptop will not respond, just a black screen', 'The screen is just blinking', 'La computadora hace un ruido raro'],
     'resolution':
         ['La computadora ha sido reemplazada', 'Laptop has been replaced', 'Screen has been replaced']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

masks = pd.DataFrame({"short_description": [False, True, False],
                      "details": [False, False, True],
                      "resolution": [True, False, False]})

df.update(df.apply(lambda col: col.loc[masks[col.name]].apply(gt.translate)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the boolean as a column in your dataframe and use `loc` to filter out the row that needs to be translated. Also, you can define a function that takes in an array and do the translation.

```
# function to translate language
def translation(array):
    return [gs.translate(i, 'en') for i in array]

df_sample['boolean'] = mask

# Condition for loc
condition = (df_sample['boolean'] == 0, ['short_description','details','resolution'])

df_sample.loc[condition] = df_sample.loc[condition].apply(lambda x: translation(x.values))
```

Comment: Can we apply this strategy one column at a time, i.e. short_description, details, resolution assuming we have unique mask list for each?

Comment: I am actually getting this error `ValueError: Must provide strings.`

Comment: @Wolfy may I ask what does it mean by unique mask list? Do you mean like translating certain rows in every column?

Comment: so the mask is to indicate where there are words that are non-english. There are 3 columns that will have their own unique mask i.e. a vector that determines whether there is english words or not. Does that make sense?

Comment: By the way, just curious, which line of code gives you the `ValueError`? Because I did not get it