# python pandas translate text to english

Tags: python, pandas, translate, translators

Hello I have a DataFrame from pandas that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"language": ["en", "it", "en", "it"],
                   "text": ["Hello", "Ciao", "This is english text", "Questo è un testo italiano"]})
```

I would like to translate all italian text to english.
How can I do this?

Comment: that seems to be a bad design

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is probably not a very good design like nbk has pointed out already.
I've answered something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74042596/translate-text-into-english-under-certain-conditions-python/74117822#74117822) a few days ago which might be helpful.

To answer your question:

Using google translator, you can do:

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
gt = GoogleTranslator(source='it', target='en')
df.loc[df.language == 'it', 'text'] = df.loc[df.language == 'it', 'text'].apply(gt.translate)
```